# Scatter-gather idea with helm

Tags: org-mode, helm

I love that I can quickly capture ideas with `org-capture`. For my academic writing, these get sent to a `scientific_journal.org` file. After a while though, I find that I have many related post, scattered throughout, which need to get grouped under a common heading or sent off into a separate document.

What I would like to do is search my capture document with helm and mark all the relevant candidates, then [TAB] to a helm action that lets me batch refile these at once.

I found some discussion of this earlier [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19405/mark-and-gather-in-org-mode) and [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-04/msg00009.html). And [John Kitchin](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/9134/john-kitchin) has some code to get this done outside of helm:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-04/msg00056.html

and he also posted some code to bulk-apply actions in helm:

http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/01/24/Anatomy-of-a-helm-source/

But, as someone who is relatively new to helm, I'm having trouble piecing the two bits together...

Any ideas?

Thanks!